Trying to find an Alright on the Night episode
I've been trying to discover which UK (It'll be) Alright on the Night episode, from the 1980s, featured a clip of a TV presenter's voice introducing a prison drama, which then cuts to some kids TV-show called (I think) The Yogs.
The clip then cuts back to a test-card backdrop with the bemused newscaster attempting to fill the time by describing the details of the show, wherein he describes the prisoners as causing  "a lot of bother".
Which number Alright on the Night show is this from?

According to various online sources, it was on the very first episode in 1977. Here's one of these sources discussing the announcer in that clip, Michael St. John:

There was also a wonderful incident involving him on the first 'It'll Be Alright On The Night', in which he was promoting an upcoming episode of 'Within These Walls'; instead of the clip he was expecting, a loud advert for The Yogs, a sort of yoghurt, ran. After that he had several minutes in which he had to ad-lib to just a caption. Classic moments."

The clip is here on Youtube and I admit, it's pretty hilarious. :)

Thanks! I tried sifting through clips on YouTube but never managed to find it.
